# AngularJS: schedule function to be executed even if browser is closed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, scheduled-tasks

I want to schedule some logic (function) to be executed after specified time offset (let's say an hour) even if the user will close the session/browser. Use case:

1) User registers for event in my system

2) System sends email notification with confirmation link

3) If user does not click on confirmation link within one hour he is losing his registration

What camed to my mind is to implement my "check time logic" in timout (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) so I will schedule function which will be executed after one hour and it will check if the given user confirmed or not, but I am wondering whether this function will be executed at all if the browser will be closed? I believe this "timout" function will be only running on client side, so when the browser is closed the function will not be executed, am I right?

What could be the solution for my problem?

Comment: You must implement the registration timeout logic on server side

Comment: You can't do that with angularjs because is running on the client.

Comment: That is what I've expected. And if I only can run php on the server how can I do it in server side? some cgi script?

Comment: Use Service Worker functionality for this. This is independent thread run in the background. Limitation is work with only Firefox, Opera and Chrome. And for that you need HTTPS enabled.

Comment: I need this functionality especially for IE and Safari unfortuntally.